# Cannot add drag-and-drop to top-level JFrame

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jframe, jsplitpane

I've got a JFrame set like this:

```
class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    JPanel left, tab1, tab2;
    JTabbedPane right;
    public MainWindow(String name)
        super(name);
        left = new JPanel();
        tab1 = new JPanel();
        tab2 = new JPanel();
        right = new JTabbedPane();
        right.addTab(tab1);
        right.addTab(tab2);
        this.getContentPane().add(splitPane);
        this.setTransferHandler(new FileTransferHandler());

    this.pack();        
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Where the `FileTransferHandler` is a TransferHandler class which imports file into the window and works well. Now I try to drag my file from external file system into the JFrame. It works but just for the spaces between the JPanels. When I drag the file onto the area of JPanels it doesn't work.

I followed the tutorial here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/toplevel.html
But in this tutorial it simply do the same thing, `this.setTransferHandler(handler)` to the main JFrame.

I tried `setTransferHandler(handler)` to all the components on the JFrame but it still worked as before. Just the spaces between them worked.

Does anyone know what's the problem here? Thanks!

Comment: for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about a.m. issue

Comment: @mKorbel Ok I'll do that

Comment: Try adding the transfer handler to the content pane directly instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, but I tried adding it to add components on the JFrame but it still worked as before. They don't respond to drop.

Comment: Try using the GlassPane, but you will to ensure that the GlassPane is visible. Basically all the components on he frame are consuming/blocking the mouse events

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's not bad, but if I still want to keep the mouse events on the components inside the content pane?

Comment: Okay, try creating a "drop zone" where files can be dragged onto and dropped